# SQLite select rows containing whole word

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select rows that contains a whole word, NOT a substring. For example from these rows:

- System works good
- I have some goodies

I need to get only first one (that contains word *good*), but with my sql query I get both of them.

```
select *
from my_tab
where my_column like '%good%'
```

Please note, I need this in sqlite, where not all usual sql functions are available.

Comment: Which version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: is it always separated by spaces, or do you need a real word boundary detection (like `,`, `.`, `(`, ...)?

Comment: @FlorianKoch separated by spaces like in example

Comment: @GurV I'm using it for Android app, version 3.9

Comment: [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) would allow searching for entire words.

Answer (score 5):

You can check it like a space between both `%` symbols and a  and `%` int end of the word and a `%` and  to the beginning of the word which you need to search.

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
where words like '% good %'
or words like 'good %'
or words like '% good';
```

Comment: OMG, it was just a simple space ;)

Comment: note that this **doesn't** work when you have a sentence like `... good, ...`

Comment: @Choletski this still won't capture all cases, e.g. `... (good work!) ...` - there are a **lot** of stopping characters to consider. Easiest example still missing is the full stop `that's good.` That's why i asked in the comment if you need a full boundary detection

Comment: use same query with some modification like -> select * from your_table_name
where words like '% good %'
or words like '%good %'
or words like '% good%';

Comment: I would add another field to the select that included a trailing and leading space and then compare that against `'% good %'`.  `select *, ' '+words+' ' as searchwords from tablename where searchwords like '% good % or searchwords like '% good.%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * 
from table
where ' '||words||' ' like '% good %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions (see https://antonz.org/sqlean-regexp/) to add additional parsing to the beginning and end of the substring your searching for, although it will add complexity and does require adding a module to the SQLite engine. One potential repository that includes the regular expression function is https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean